# Update DNS for domain name in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dns

We have DNS failover setup, with a TTL of 180 seconds. When a server fails, it updates the IP address on the A Host records to that of the working server. Currently, our website refreshes using AJAX requests on an interval. When one of the servers fails, the DNS is updated and failed over, so if you ping the domain it has the proper IP. For some reason though, inside the browser and long after the TTL has expired, the AJAX request still retains the old IP address assigned to the domain name (note the page cannot be reloaded in the browser). I am aware as of reading other questions that you cannot force a flush of the DNS cache on the client. My question is, do any of you know another way or trick to accomplish this using javascript or AJAX? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an X/Y problem to me; you're only in this situation due to the shortcomings of your infrastructure ... browsers are notorious for DNS retention, probably for performance reasons, so I wouldn't go down this path unless my job were at stake :)

Comment: It comes down to a high availability solution. We have two servers that provide data via ajax request. Since the web app is client-side, it will not be refreshed in the browser. The AJAX refresh will occur on intervals, and the domain name in the ajax will stay the same, however will have an updated IP when a server fails. If there is no way of doing this, do you know how I could redesign the site / ajax request for high availability with two servers handling the request? Thanks

Comment: Just some wishful thinking: if you would do the requests to another server that's always up and never changes their ip and from that server you do a `cURL`(or something like that) and return the response? So, you use `the-always-up-server` as some kind of router?

Comment: Hi where would put an always up server ? New York? Western seaboard? China? grafted on to an ocean floor cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two (or more) subdomains. eg. data1.example.com and data2.example.com that correspond to the physical servers.

However, for cross domain to work, you need to set `document.domain` which allows the communication between domains:

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

Then, you need your script to fail over between the different servers manually. It is the only way that I know of and has been successful in many installs.

Answer (score 4):

I would not attempt this client side, I would use a network load balancer, or some other server side virtual IP address.

To do as you request client side, would require that your AJAX calls are made in such a way as to either avoid browser security or fullly conform to cross domain requests. If you are happy to make these changes, then there are some JavaScript DNS libs, these can be used to resolve the DNS name to an IP address or CName, use the returned IP address or CName to adjust your AJAX url, and refresh the AJAX url using a new DNS lookup whenever an AJAX call fails.

I wouldn't want to do this myself

Comment: It doesn't have to go cross-domain, because there are more than 1 A Host record for the name. Basically, the 1 domain named is configured in round robin, and when a server goes down, the round robin just keeps sending the same ip. Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy gives details. For the approach to work you will have to stop using the browser DNS resolution and take control yourself, as the browser is still stuck with the old dead IP address. therefore the page that was loaded when the server was not dead and the ajax request for new data will be considered different origin's.

Comment: Can you provide some links to those libs?

Answer (score 1):

I would either:

- code the ajax to hit server primary.mycompany.com , if that fails, then switch to secondary.mycompany.com , if that fails, back to primary.
- preferably make the failover setup take over a "service ip" from the failed host. There exist good solutions for this.

For linux google stuff like heartbeat and virtual ip and whatnot.

Comment: This is the solution that I have used in the past and is the only reliable one (other than having a more reliable network infrastructure). I remember blackberries in particular, being notoriously stubborn. Use two public names and have the ajax request auto-failover to the other.

Answer (score 0):

With the browser Firefox, `dns.resolve()` method can Resolves DNS of given domains.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve